# May I map n records to 1 table view row with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my application, I use Core Data as well as NSFetchedResultsController. I need to use 1 table view row to display 9 records instead of 1 record. So I customise the `numberOfRowsInSection`

method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [self numberOfRowsForNumber: [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsForNumber:(NSInteger)num
{
    NSInteger a = num / 9;
    NSInteger b = num % 9;
    return a + (b == 0 ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Adding the first record is OK. But when I add the second record, there is an error:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1330
2013-11-13 06:54:56.217 TestNSFetchedResultsController[2693:a0b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Does it mean NSFetchedResultsController support 1 record to 1 row mapping only? Or is there better way to accomplish it?

Comment: You probably need to customise the delegate methods which will be trying to add items to the tableView in response to you adding new records.  You might want to consider creating some other grouping entity that has a relationship with the 9 records and select this in the fetchedResultsController and then just customise the tableView Cell to show the associated 9 records which you could retrieve from the grouping entities relationship property.  I would try customising the delegate methods first so they match the customised data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just customise methods of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. For example, I define customised `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`, `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` cases of `didChangeObject` method.

Thank @Duncan Groenewald for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with the `TLIndexPathController` class from [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) if you're OK with using an `NSFetchedResultsController` alternative. It rolls all five `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods into a single `didUpdateDataModel` method, so it is generally easier to work with. But more to your needs,  it provides a `willUpdateDataModel` delegate method that lets you map your fetched managed objects into an arbitrary data model. Here is an example mapping the objects into groups of nine:

```
- (TLIndexPathDataModel *)controller:(TLIndexPathController *)controller willUpdateDataModel:(TLIndexPathDataModel *)oldDataModel withDataModel:(TLIndexPathDataModel *)updatedDataModel
{
    NSArray *ungroupedItems = updatedDataModel.items;
    NSMutableArray *groupedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *group;
    for (id object in ungroupedItems) {
        if (!group) {
            group = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:9];
        }
        [group addObject:object];
        if (group.count == 9 || object == [ungroupedItems lastObject]) {
            [groupedItems addObject:group];
            group = nil;
        }
    }
    return [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:groupedItems];
}
```

Without going into too much detail about how TLIndexPathTools works (see the [readme](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools)), you write your view controller code against the [`TLIndexPathDataModel` API](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html). So when you do the above mapping, your view controller just needs to be aware that the items in the data model are arrays of managed objects.

There are a couple of sample projects worth checking out:

1. The "Core Data" project demonstrates the Core Data integration
2. The "No Results" project demonstrates using the above delegate method to display a "no results" row anytime the data model contains zero items.

The one caveat is that TLIndexPathTools was only designed to scale to a few thousand items. So if you've got a really big data set, you might run into performance issues.